# Averages of a differentiable function at zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Assume that $f:R^n \to R$ is a continuous function and differentiable at $0$.

> Prove that $\lim_{r \to 0^+}\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)}f(x)-f(0)dx=0$

I managed to prove this in one dimension but i have a problem proving it at many dimensions in which i also used polar coordinates to reduce the problem in one dimension.

> A function $f:R^n \to R$ is differentiable at zero if $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{|f(x)-f(0)-<\nabla{f}(0),x>|}{|x|}=0$

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)}[f(x)-f(0)]dx=\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)}[f(x)-f(0)- \langle \nabla f(0), x \rangle ]dx$ because the last term in the integrand is an odd function. Now you can bound the integrand  by $\epsilon \|x\|<\epsilon r$ for $x \in B(0,r)$ and $r$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Why is the last term symmetric?Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @MariosGretsas The integral of a function $g$ over ball $B(0,r)$ around the origin is $0$ if $g(-x)=-g(x)$. [By the change of variable $y=-x$ in the integral].

Comment: I did not remember that the integral of an odd function  over a ball is zero..Thanks